# Full OS Restore of Non-Rooted Devices

Tags: restore

I recently looked at [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices) and found some very useful information as to how to backup android without rooting your device. However, I can't seem to find out much information on how to restore your device without rooting once you've backed it up. The answers that do tell how to restore all assume that your device can successfully boot into Android, and not all of the answers refer to backing up Android OS itself, instead focusing on apps.
I want to find a way to restore my OS because I'm going to be rooting my phone, and installing a lot of custom roms, and I want to make sure I can restore my phone before risking breaking it. Also, stop trying to mark this question as a duplicate, as I am trying to delete my duplicate question.

Comment: Your earlier question was on the same lines: [How to Backup and Restore Android OS without Rooting](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/137473)

Answer (score 0):

Let me state a thing, before explaining what I deem to be the best practice: rooting is necessary, in order to fully back up your system. Without said permission, a backup app wouldn't be able to fully access other apps' files, therefore leading to incomplete backups.

I'm now going to explain the best, deepest kind of backup. It requires you to install a custom recovery (such as ClockworkMod or TWRP), and consists of a full backup of your phone's status. It's called "Nandroid Backup", and you could think about it as a photograph of your system and data. Please note that changing recovery, just as rooting your phone, **will void your warranty**.

For non-rooted phones, you may rely on third-party apps such as Titanium Backup, which can backup an app with all of its relevant data. While this is handy in the case you need to backup just a few apps, it can be tedious to manually save a whole system, not to mention that the app's features are limited in its free version, and in the case of the phone being non-rooted.